# Difference between after_setup_theme and init action hooks?

Tags: hooks, actions, init

What is the difference between the `after_setup_theme` and `init` action hooks? It seems they are both called right before any page in WordPress is loaded (even admin pages).

Answer (score 29):

`after_setup_theme` action hook is fired before the actual `$wp->init();` which Set up the current user and only then `init` action hook is fired which means that they are pretty much the same with one major difference  and that is at `after_setup_theme` the user is not authenticated, and at `init` he is (assuming that we are talking about an actual user).

Comment: Just an addition to Bainternet's great answer. You can see execution order of hooks in here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference . And you can see all hooks and differences between *after_setup_theme* and *init*