# On which hook should I be calling register_nav_menu(s)?

Tags: menus, hooks, customization

I've variously seen `register_nav_menus()` called:

- on `after_setup_theme`
- on `init`
- pasted "loose" into `functions.php`

with no apparent change in functionality.

Which hook should I be using to call this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you should not register functions *loose* in `functions.php` because you cannot remove them (using `remove_action`). It can also cause debug errors since WP may not yet be stable. By using a hook you are making sure WP is stable enough to run your code, and what you need to use has been loaded.

Check out the answer on the [Wordpress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/whento-use-init-and-when-to-use-a-function-in-functionsphp#post-5734584) for more info

---

To decide which hook to use, first check out [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14800/84836).

The main difference between the two:

- The user is not authenticated at `after_setup_theme`
- The user becomes authenticated at `init`.

The `after_setup_theme` hook is therefore obviously run before `init`, you can see this in the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

According to the Wordpress Codex page on `after_setup_theme`:

> This hook is called during each page load, after the theme is
>   initialized. It is generally used to perform basic setup,
>   **registration**, and init actions for a theme.

---

Since you are registering menus, I would suggest using `after_setup_theme`. The [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) for `register_nav_menu()` also uses the `after_setup_theme` hook in one of the examples.

Comment: *...there is really not much of a problem with registering it loosly in functions.php*. Not true. You cannot remove these with a simple `remove_action` from a child theme or a plugin. **NEVER** do that

Comment: I edited my answer, and added a link to a post on the Wordpress Forums discussing it

Answer (score 1):

You can use them the moment they are available i.e. as soon as `functions.php` is loaded, hence why you've seen so many different options.

I would recommend sticking with the "defacto" way - using the hook `after_setup_theme`

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [`register_nav_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) show an example using the `after_setup_theme` hook so I would use that.

[`after_setup_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme)

> This hook is called during each page load, after the theme is initialized. It is generally used to perform basic setup, registration, and init actions for a theme.
>
> ...the after_setup_theme hook, which runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such as indicating support post thumbnails.